# how to get the current window id or something of a outlook new email window.?

Tags: c#, outlook

I have a ribbon button in outlook new message window.
The purpose of the button is .. 
If anyone pressed the button then a flag will set true.

During mail send I want to implement custom logic base on that flag.

But the problem is if i open two windows then the flag value holds the current window's status which is normal.

How can i get the current windows ItemSend event or current window's flag value.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't assign any ID to its windows. Instead, you can use a Window handle (Windows API). To get the handle you need to cast the inspector or explorer window to the [IOLEWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680102(v=vs.85).aspx) interface and use the [GetWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687282(v=vs.85).aspx) method which retrieves the handle.

Also you can use the CurrentItem property of the Inspector class to get the shown Outlook item object. Saved items have the [EntryID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866458(v=office.15).aspx) property value set which allowsto get the unique Entry ID of the object. Here is what MSDN states:

> A MAPI store provider assigns a unique ID string when an item is created in its store. Therefore, the EntryID property is not set for an Outlook item until it is saved or sent. The Entry ID changes when an item is moved into another store, for example, from your Inbox to a Microsoft Exchange Server public folder, or from one Personal Folders (.pst) file to another .pst file. Solutions should not depend on the EntryID property to be unique unless items will not be moved.

You may also consider adding a user property with your own ID.

Answer (score 0):

In the event handler of your button, you are passed the Control parameter (of type IRibbonControl). Read the IRibbonControl.Context property and cast it to the Inspector object. You can then read the Inspector.CurrentItem property to retrieve the item being shown.

You can also use Application.ActiveInspector (and then Inspector.CurrentItem) - for the user to click your button, the inspector should become active, hence Application.ActiveInspector will retrieve inspector hosting your button.

Comment: yes I know but there is a problem.
suppose user clicked my button in new message window.
Then user opened another new message window and it became the Application.ActiveInspector.

Comment: A soon as the user clicks the button, your event handler will be invoked. The user will not be able to  do anything (including opening another message) until your event handler returns. It is all synchronous and happens on the main Outlook thread. If you are worried that can still happen, the first solution (IRibbonControl.Context etc.) will work just fine.